# GWT-libGDX platform specific code

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I am currently developing with libGDX a cross-platform game. I want to compile code conditioned on which platform I am on.
e.g. if I am compiling with GWT it should choose Class.js.java, when running normally with Java it should choose Class.java.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to GWT's "super-source" feature, which allows you to substitute alternate sources for classes when compiling for GWT.

See the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) in the section titled "Overriding one package implementation with another" for details on how that works.

Comment: Thanks :D That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. You can create an interface contract and each module should implement that.

In your core module you create the interface, since that needs to be shared with the other modules.

```
public interface MultiPlatformContract {
    String whatPlatform();
}
```

You also create a constructor for your main core class where you add this implementation as a parameter. I just call it here but you can store it, pass it along to other objects and call any of it's methods later.

```
public MultiPlatformGame(MultiPlatform multiPlatformContract)
{
    System.out.println(multiPlatform.whatPlatform());
}
```

As soon as you add this contract to the constructor all your modules will obviously fail since you need to supply a implementation to it's constructor. So we create an implementation for each module we want to develop for. You can create this in core but it makes more sense to create it in the specific module since each module should use one for it's own purpose.

```
public class DesktopPlatform implements MultiPlatformContract {    
    public String whatPlatform() {
        return "I run on desktop."
    }
}
```

In your main class / entry point for each platform module, where you instantiate you game you got an error now since you need to supply a `MultipPlatformContract` to the constructor. On desktop I pass it the desktop implementation of the contract.

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    new LwjglApplication(new LibGdxTest(new DesktopPlatform()), config);
}
```

That's it. This is mostly used to access different API's. Like the Steam API should be accessed from Desktop and Google Play should be implemented for Android.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: But I believe that this will now solve my issue. The problem is that I have Java code which compiles well, but can't be compiled with GWT for html. So I need some sort of conditional compilation (if GWT compile file A else compile file B). I could adapt my code such that it is compiled with GWT, but the workaround is inefficient for Java.
To summarise I need the efficient code for Java, and the inefficient workaround for GWT

Comment: it is basically about the instanceof function, which doesn't compile on GWT but needs some workaround

Comment: @orestiszambounis Your not making any sense. Platform specific code goes into the corresponding modules. The specific module gets only compiled for that specific platform.

Comment: Listen, you come here with a question but you already are biased to a certain hacky method. I just gave you a proper solution but you do not want to use that. All fine by me, however don't make comments like that. I devoted time and effort to help you out and the least you could do is to respect that.

Comment: Well respect is mutual right? btw, https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code
Still thanks for your help